QR-Code with location and via
By now the use of 'geo:' with decimal latitude and longitude appears to be fairly well accepted, even if some services would prefer you to use their proprietary encodings. Hence something like
qrencode -s 6 -o geo.png 'geo:50.891075,0.154269,35'

Is there a variant of this which can also encode a single 'via' point?
The specific case I'm thinking of is "deliver to this building, via /this/ entrance which is the only one suitable for heavy vehicles".
Updated: The altitude is Geoid (WGS-84) relative but is frequently omitted. The overall format is described by RFC-5870 as a known URI, but there is nothing in there about concatenating even a limited number of points to incorporate a via or waypoint.
Either of these links work:
https://maps.app.goo.gl/NYeAYbgiQmM1RYa9A
https://www.google.com/maps/dir/50.89456,0.15404/50.891075,0.154269/
and I suspect that Google provides waypoint etc. facilities which would be useful.
However, particularly when multiple companies are involved (a site owner, a supplier and possibly a courier) I consider it very bad practice to gratuitously introduce additional commercial parties: even indispensable nuisances such as Google or Apple in order to use their "free" mapping services.

Maybe take two steps back and tell us something about what you're trying to achieve in what kind of environment and using which software.

Pointing a 'phone at a QR code encoding a geo: location will, generally speaking, allow them to open a mapping app with that location highlighted. I am, as I said, trying to guide the user to a specific point via a specific entry location.

So, you want said code to either contain two points, or a route from via to entrance.

Specifically as I said in my question: "deliver to this building, via /this/ entrance". A geo: encoding works fine for a single point (and has been discussed here multiple times). I'm not aware of a via: encoding, although I believe that there are proprietary encodings for e.g. a Google Maps route encoded as a URL: I'd like to avoid that sort of thing if possible.

Re altitude, leaving it out (undefined) = ground level, any value is relative to the WGS-84 geoid RFC5870 (s.3.4.5), simple Wikipedia explanation.

@user2856 Yep, just got to that one and will edit the question to remove one possible source of confusion. Following the URI route, I've not got anywhere useful looking for anything related to "via", "track", "route"... in fact the last of those was predictably worse than useless.

The RFC is explicit about a geo URI encoding a single point.  I think you might be out of luck looking for a standard.
